# dropdownlist item text is always failing in if condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a div with texbox inside, only when the dropdownlist selected item text is equal to "Other"

From below, I want to show a div 'divOtherIncident' only when the dropdownlist item text 'Other' is selected. If something else is selected, a
popover should appear(this bit is working fine)

I have two issues in here.

1) For all the selected item text including "Other", it always goes to else condition. I could see the alert showing the text other, but it never goes into if condition
2) The div never shows or hide,

Could anyone please help.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedIncident, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIncident, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { data_toggle = "popover", @class = "form-control", @id = "IncidentId" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedIncident, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group hidden" id="divOtherIncident">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherIncident, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherIncident, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tbOtherIncident"} })             
            </div>
        </div>

        $("#IncidentId").change(function () {
                var ddlOIValue = $("#IncidentId option:selected").text();
                alert(ddlOIValue); //This displays the text 'Other' but it never goes into if condition below
                if (ddlOIValue == "Other") {    
                    $('#divOtherIncident').show();  

                }
                else {  
                        $('#divOtherIncident').hide();      
                        $("#tbOtherIncident").val("");  
                        $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetActionDetails")',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        data: { id: $("#IncidentId").val() },
                        success: function (data) {                          
                            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                                html: true,
                                content: data
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                            alert('Failed to retrieve action details' + ex);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;                       
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your drop down looks like but if the dropdown text and value is not the same then your condition would always fail.

So try to get the selected value instead and not the text. ie:

```
var ddlOIValue = $('#IncidentId').val();
```

or

```
var ddlOIValue = $("#IncidentId option:selected").val();
```

See difference in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akassama/qc1ouo4n/1/)